# How would one model a Neutrophil Extracellular Trap with Hookean Springs?

Tags: dna, biophysics

This is a question based in biology but involves a good amount of physics.

Given that a Neutrophil Extracellular Trap (N.E.T) behaves like an aggregate of DNA strands with citrullinated Histones and defensins such as Myeloperoxidase and Neutrophil Elastase, and that DNA itself can be modeled as a Hookean spring (maybe with a variable spring "constant"), I thought that it would be possible to model say a 100 uM X 100 uM Neutrophil Extracellular trap as a network of hookean springs.

I think that this would require one to ascertain the length of the DNA strands incorporated into the N.E.T as well as the configuration of these many strands. The configuration will determine whether the spring constants of each DNA strand are additive (for parallel springs).

Is there some approximation of configuration and DNA length I could use to maybe get one cumulative spring constant for a N.E.T of a given size or is more complex notation required? Also the purpose of my asking this question and even modeling a N.E.T as a network of springs is to gauge the compliance and compressive stress that can be generated by the N.E.T.